# I understand decorators on a base level but am confused by @django.display()

Tags: python, django

Working through the django tutorials and came across the following code:

```
@admin.display(
    boolean=True,
    ordering='pub_date',
    description='Published recently?',
)
```

Had no idea what it was so I did some googling and learned what decorators are in Python. I feel comfortable with that topic.

However, in all the videos and docs I went through I didn't see an example like `@admin.display()`

Only things like `@log` or `@timer`. Pretty much just a simple class or function decorator.

**My guess is that `@admin.display` is a decorator where `admin` is the class and `display` is one of many wrapper methods(is that even possible) in that class?**

Just confused I guess as to the syntax as I can't find any examples like it :(

Comment: Your guess would be right. `admin` is the class (or module, whoops). The `decorator` is just a `method` of the class, or imported into the module. There is also `admin.site.register()`, which is the non-decorator method of `admin.register()`, it is imported into the admin module from `django.contrib.admin.decorators`

Comment: It is more like that `admin` is a module than a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to parse this is:

- `@` is special decorator syntax
- `admin` and its attribute `display` are both objects
- the `(boolean=True, ...)` means `display` must be callable, i.e. `display.__call__()` will be executed

When you see something like:

```py
@log
def my_method():
    return 'blah'
```

It's effectively the same as: `my_method = log(my_method)`

Next, consider:

```py
@configurable_log(config_val)
def my_method():
    return 'blah'
```

Which is the same as: `my_method = configurable_log(config_val)(my_method)`

`configurable_log` is a callable taking config args (i.e. `configurable_log(config_val)`) which returns another callable, which is passed `my_method`. In other words, it's the same as:

```py
configured_log_decor = configurable_log(config_val)
@configured_log_decor  # a "no parens" decorator
def my_method():
    return 'blah'
```

The last remaining part is just normal attribute access, e.g.:

```py
SomeClass.attr_of_class
some_instance.attr_of_instance
some_module.attr_of_module
```